# Creating derived attribute using character counts in PySpark

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Currently I have a df, where I need to count the characters in one column and create 3 columns. Counting f, g and h characters for each column.(If no character is present, then keep value as is.)

[image]

Expected Result:

[image]

My current approach is in python:

```
collist = ['A']
For i in collist:
  df['{}_f'.format(i)] = df[i].apply(lambda x: x if x is None else str(x).count('f') if len([i for i in list(set(x)) if i in ['f','g','h']]) > 0  else int(x))
  df['{}_g'.format(i)] = df[i].apply(lambda x: x if x is None else str(x).count('g') if len([i for i in list(set(x)) if i in ['f','g','h']]) > 0  else int(x))
  df['{}_h'.format(i)] = df[i].apply(lambda x: x if x is None else str(x).count('h') if len([i for i in list(set(x)) if i in ['f','g','h']]) > 0  else int(x))
```

**Looking to replicate the same in PySpark for faster processing as I have to implement in multiple columns.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never encountered this use case before in my entire experience with Spark. I, however, cannot find a "built-in" way to achieve that yet, so I'm using UDF instead. It should be fine with a fair amount of data.

```py
def count_letter(x, c):
    if x is None:
        return x
    if len([i for i in list(set(x)) if i in ['f','g','h']]) > 0:
        return x.count(c)
    return int(x)

(df
    .withColumn('A_f', F.udf(count_letter, T.StringType())(F.col('A'), F.lit('f')))
    .withColumn('A_g', F.udf(count_letter, T.StringType())(F.col('A'), F.lit('g')))
    .withColumn('A_h', F.udf(count_letter, T.StringType())(F.col('A'), F.lit('h')))
    .show()
)

# Output
# +--------+---+---+---+
# |       A|A_f|A_g|A_h|
# +--------+---+---+---+
# |ffffffff|  8|  0|  0|
# |      -2|  0|  0|  0|
# |      hh|  0|  0|  2|
# |hhhggggh|  0|  4|  4|
# |       g|  0|  1|  0|
# +--------+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Thanks for the UDF, only row 2 doesn’t get handled but rest looks fine.

Comment: I just updated the UDF to match with your original function